# how to connect to port on the host from the container

Tags: docker

I have tcp port i.e.'3003' opened on host (1.1.1.1) and trying to connect to host port from container running on this host '**curl -v 1.1.1.1:3003**' but getting '*curl: (7) Failed to connect to 1.1.1.1 port 3003: No route to host*'. I can ping 1.1.1.1 from container without a problem. Container is connected to bridge network on host

Of course I can connect to port '3003' from host itself '**curl -v 1.1.1.1:3003**' , getting *Connected to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) port 3003 (#0)*.

Using docker 1.12 on RHEL7.

Comment: Is the container running a firewall which is blocking outgoing connections on port 3003 ?

Comment: no I don't think, no iptables etc. And it looks like I can connect to tcp ports on external hosts, but not on the host container is running on

Comment: Is the target service running directly on the host, or within a container itself? I.e. are you trying to connect from one container to another through the published port?

Comment: target service is on the host and I am trying to connect to it from container running on this host